# Dynamic imports for Ionic 2 outside of "node_modules"

Tags: typescript, npm, ionic2, dependencies

I've read the description for `ModuleResulution` for typescript at this page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node

From what I understand is that all the files which I want to import MUST be in the `node_modules` directory. Is there a way to import files that are not located in this directory?

Let's say I have the following directory structure (`src/MyApp/`):

```
├── Console
│   └── Console.ts 
├── Interfaces
│   └── CredentialsInterface.ts 
└── Service
    ├── Authentication.ts
    ├── Router.ts
    └── Connector.ts
```

Then for example in my `src/pages/login/login.ts` I use this to import `Console.ts`:

```
import { Console } from '../../MyApp/Console/Console';
```

But I want to achieve something like this:

```
import { Console } from '@MyApp/Console/Console';
```

Where the `@MyApp` is an alias for `src/MyApp`.

Because of potential file / folder relocations or refactoring later I might want to replace the location of my files, but I do not want to go through all my files manually to change the "hardcoded" path if that makes sense, and I know for a fact that this is possible for other tools like [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Is this in any way possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try setting `path` in tsconfig.json?

Comment: I've tried that.. it didn't work. The reason for this is probably because that only works for "classic" module resolution, or I had just set my path wrong. Will that work even if my module resolution is set to "node"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you have to update a couple of files, you can do it by updating the `tsconfig.json` and extending the webpack configuration file.

On `tsconfig.json` you need add on `compilerOptions`:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "app/*": [
    "app/*"
  ],
  "@env": [
    "environments/environment"
  ],
  "interfaces/*": [
    "interfaces/*"
  ],
  "providers/*": [
    "providers/*"
  ],
  "validators/*": [
    "validators/*"
  ]
}
```

I leave a link to a brief documentation that I did that implements this and also uses the enviroments of `angular-cli`

[Ionic envs and beauty paths](https://github.com/gabfiocchi/ionic-envs)